# malloc'ing and realloc'ing pointers causing memory leaks on return

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I was told to write a wrapper that takes a starting address of a location and number 'n' for the size. Later, use this memory to store something.
I was able to write the code, but there's a memory leak in the program.
This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int alloc_func(char *newptr, int size)
{
    newptr = (char *)realloc(newptr, size);
    printf("In func: %p\n", newptr);
    if(NULL == newptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *foo = "Computer";  //string to be copied to newly allocated memory

    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    printf("Before return: %p\n", ptr);
    int size = 10, flag;

    flag = alloc_func(ptr, size);

    printf("After return: %p\n", ptr);

    if(flag == 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    else{
        strcpy(ptr, foo);
    }

    printf("The copied string is: %s\n", ptr);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
```

}

On running valgrind, the leak summary says
"definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 block"

This is happening because I'm sending the ptr (starting address) as a pointer value to the function and hence the function is creating a copy of the pointer, i.e., newptr in the program. This newptr is getting realloc'ed to 10 locations. Since I'm not returning the newptr, once the function ends, my 'realloc'ed' locations would go out of scope and lost.

My doubt is:

a) even if a copy of the pointer is created, both ptr and newptr will be pointing to the same memory location, then why would it leak?

b) Isn't malloc'ed variables 'global' ?

c) Is the leak happening because I'm not passing the address of the pointer so that no copy would be created? (I tried this, but I want to know why)

d) In my main, what is free(ptr doing then)? Just clearing the ptr malloc'ed for 1?

e) Is there any way to check if the allocation of that 10 'size'bytes was a success?

Comment: After `realloc` the `ptr` is not necessarily equals to `newptr` as it passed by value and `realloc` might return a different pointer. And voila - your `ptr` is pointing to a wrong location, and there is some lost memory around. Freeing `ptr` is causing UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm printing the address of pointers before ,after calls and inside the function. All the addresses are same i.e., newptr and ptr are pointing to same address. How? And if I try to access ptr in main after function call, since ptr doesn't have updated memory, it has to give seg fault. But, how is the program working fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your alloc_func() method should be:

```
int alloc_func(char **newptr, int size)
{
    char *p = (char *)realloc(*newptr, size);
    printf("In func: %p\n", p);
    if(NULL == p) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        *newptr = p;
        return 1;
}
```

and you call it with

```
flag = alloc_func(&ptr, size);
```

That way ptr will get changed.

Comment: Corner case: Code calling `alloc_func(&ptr, 0);` may not properly update `ptr` as `realloc(*newptr, 0)` may return `NULL` and not be an out-of-memroy condition.

Comment: @FredK. Thanks. Aren't malloc'd variables global? I mean they are allocated on heap, so it has to be accessible from anywhere. Am i right?

Comment: That's not the problem, infoseeker.    The problem is that your version of the function accesses the first argument (`newptr`) by value.   Changes of `newptr` itself (inside your function) do not affect the value of `ptr` in `main()`.   FredK's solution corrects that - it's why he's changed the argument from a pointer into a pointer to pointer, and assigns to `*newptr` inside the function rather than `newptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of `newptr` in `alloc_func`. However, that is only a local change. It does not change the value the pointer in the calling function. As a consequence, you have a dangling pointer and a memory leak.

The calling function has a dangling pointer.
`alloc_func` has a memory leak.

You need to return the newly allocated pointer from `alloc_func` to the calling function. You can do that either through the returned value or by changing the argument to a pointer to a pointer.

**Solution 1: Return a pointer**

```
char* alloc_func(char *newptr, int size)
{
    newptr = (char *)realloc(newptr, size);
    printf("In func: %p\n", newptr);
    return newptr;
}
```

and change the call in `main` to:

```
ptr = alloc_func(ptr, size); // not flag = ...
```

**Solution 2: Change the argument type**

```
int alloc_func(char **newptr, int size)
{
    *newptr = (char *)realloc(*newptr, size);
    printf("In func: %p\n", *newptr);
    if(NULL == *newptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

and change the call in `main` to:

```
flag = alloc_func(&ptr, size); // Use &ptr, not ptr
```